# Cryptographer TypeError: First argument must be a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

So I'm trying to create a Unit test for some pincode/password hashing. I came across this error earlier aswell, but then I was able to solve it with a simple `.toString()`, but now that doesn't seem to work.

This is some of my code related to the methods:

pin.model.spec.js:

```
let pin = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
let hash = await Pincode.getHashedPincode(pin.toString(), salt);
```

crypto.js:

```
function getPasswordHash(password, salt) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    crypto.pbkdf2(password, new Buffer(salt, 'hex'), iterations, keyLength, 'SHA1', (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      return resolve(result.toString('hex'));
    });
  });
}
```

Dont worry about the inconsistant method names, between them there is a method called `getHashedPincode` the does nothing else but calls `getPasswordHash` just for naming conventions. The vars `iterations` and `keyLength` come from a constants file. So that is not the issue either.

I hope someone can lead me to the right direction

EDIT:

This is the whole `getHashPincode`:

```
Pincode.getHashedPincode = async (pincode, salt) => {
  return cryptographer.getPasswordHash(pincode, salt);
};
```

Comment: can you show us `getHashedPincode`?

Comment: I edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `pin.toString()`.

What's causing the error is `new Buffer(salt, 'hex')`, since you specified an encoding (**hex**) then the first argument (**salt**) must be a string.
`salt.toString()` should do the trick

Comment: You are my hero, I completely missed that. But it seems to work indeed!